# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException on TCP Server

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception, sqljdbc, mssql-jdbc

I'm writting a basic TCP Server in java with Eclipse, and I'm trying to execute a MSSQL Stored Procedure after receiving an specific packet from the client.
I'm able to log everything, but when I try to insert the row, this error appears:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

Tried to google for solution but nothing works, keeps giving me that error.
Here is my classpath xml (the jar files are there):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/home/leandro/workspace/LHub/sqljdbc4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="/home/leandro/workspace/LHub/sqljdbc.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

This is my connection to db class for the insert:

```
package servers;

import java.sql.*;

public class LServerDBConn {

    private Statement stmt;
    private String DriverName = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
    private String url = "jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://192.168.x.x;databaseName=XXX";
    private String DBuser = "sa";
    private String DBpassword = "123123";

    public void connectionText(String query) throws ClassNotFoundException,SQLException {
        Class.forName(this.DriverName);

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(this.url, this.DBuser, this.DBpassword);

        this.stmt = con.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("EXEC SPI_TK103_PACKET" + query);
        if (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("DBConnection success");
        } else {
            System.out.println("DBConnection failure");
        }
        con.close();
    }

}
```

This is in my main class:

```
LServerDBConn con = new LServerDBConn();
con.connectionText(new String(buf, 0, bytes_read));
```

Thanks for any help.

[EDIT] It seems to be a problem with the files. The project is not reading the files therefore it can't find the classes. I tried with JTDS and the same happens. I think i'm mmissing some configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the

> sqljdbc4.jar or sqljdbc.jar

in your classpath.

Edit (how to include it in your classpath) 
The classpath is not easy to explain in one quick answer you will need to look at [classpath wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29), basically you have to tell your java application where to look for jars/resources to load into its classpath.

Linux

> java -classpath '/home/leandro/workspace/LHub/*:' YourApp

Download the tar.gz and extract it to get the jar 
Try downloading it from [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774)

Comment: but how should the be written in the xml?

Comment: I have both files in the project folder. Also in /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-common/ext folder (or something like that)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll give it a try and let you know.

Comment: Is there a way to configure the classpath from the inside? so I can execute java -jar FILE.jar without -classpath parameter?

Comment: There is a way but it may not be what you want but it goes something like this. Once your project is ready make a jar with all your classes, when you create the jar include the jdbc jar in it and add set the manifest of the jar to include your class with the main method and the classpath. The best way to do this I find is normally using ant, but you can craft it in many other ways including manually. Java is an amazing language but the packaging system leaves a lot to be desired...